# IE10 not working with an rgba triangle or :before/after triangles

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I just noticed a problem that is only happening in IE10, works in IE9, and I can't exactly put my finger on what is happening. I am using a lot of rgba elements on my site and IE10 seems to run them all just fine. The only problem it is having is processing something like this:

```
.links:before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 105px solid transparent;
  border-right: 105px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.77);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I then thought maybe it is just because of the Pseudo elements that IE10 doesn't like. So I tried :

```
.linkTri {
  border-left: 105px solid transparent;
  border-right: 105px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.77);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I then just added it into there as a semitransparent triangle to get around IE hating everything but, sadly, it did not work as well. It just displays the triangle as a solid white triangle.

Any ideas?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/Q8bYx/1/) (Doesn't seem to display IE problem in the fiddle)

[Live site](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/redesign/large.php) (This will show the problem)

I also just tried `opacity: 0.77;` but same problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the semitransparent triangle isn't truly showing through to the background of the page, if that is what you need. For that effect, perhaps try creating two right triangles using both `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, where your border color matches the background color of the list. For example:

```
.links:before,
.links:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  border: solid #c7c7c7;
}

.links:before {
  left: 0;
  border-width: 25px 105px 0 0;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.links:after {
  right: 0;
  border-width: 25px 0 0 105px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

If you are cool with not showing the dashed line borders on the right and left, you could try something like this: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AkOPoXI/1/). (If that styling is needed, you could wrap the list inside another element, and style that accordingly.)

Works in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, IE10. Didn't test beyond that.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your time and effort! I will try this out in a few or after lunch. With the ACA starting to go in effect soon I have a crazy amount of work to do by today for this site ha.

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much! It is causing the dashes to not continue onto the after/before element but I already have a way of fixing this.